# Как правильно: "это две разные вещи" или "это две разных вещи"?

Tags: синтаксис

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы. Считается, что они немного отличаются стилистически или даже оттенками смысла, но это настолько тонкий момент, что им лучше не заморачиваться.